# Make two inputs dependent on each other

Tags: r, shiny

In my app, I can select car names, and this first selection updates two additional inputs: the category of the car (A or B) and the range of `mpg`. I can do it so far, but I have some trouble when I try to make those two additional inputs dependent on each other. The reason I want to make these dependent on each other is that these two inputs are not "ordered", meaning that one input is not more important than the other.

In the example below, I selected 4 cars, some being in A category and others in B category. When I select only category B, the range is updated so that it corresponds to the cars in the category that I selected.

This works in this order (changing the first input updates the range), but I can't figure out how to make these two inputs dependent on each other. For example, when I reduce the `mpg` range to 20-21, the only category left in the table is A, so the first input should only show A. Adding another `observeEvent()` after the definition of `third_data()` makes both inputs empty.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

mtcars$category <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 16)
mtcars2 <- mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("car_name")

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("car_name", "car name", unique(mtcars2$car_name), 
              multiple = TRUE, selected = c("Mazda RX4", "Dodge Challenger", 
                                            "AMC Javelin", "Camaro Z28")),
  selectInput("category", "category", NULL, multiple = TRUE),
  sliderInput("range_mpg", "range of mpg",
              min = 0,
              max = 0,
              value = c(0, 0)),
  tableOutput("test_table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  first_data <- reactive({
    mtcars2 %>%
      filter(car_name %in% input$car_name)
  })
  
  observeEvent(first_data(), {
    updateSelectInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "category",
      choices = unique(first_data()$category),
      selected = unique(first_data()$category)
    )
    updateSliderInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "range_mpg",
      min = min(first_data()$mpg),
      max = max(first_data()$mpg),
      value = c(min(first_data()$mpg), max(first_data()$mpg))
    )
  })
  
  second_data <- reactive({
    first_data() %>%
      filter(category %in% input$category)
  })
  
  observeEvent(second_data(), {
    updateSliderInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "range_mpg",
      min = min(second_data()$mpg),
      max = max(second_data()$mpg),
      value = c(min(second_data()$mpg), max(second_data()$mpg))
    )
  })
  
  third_data <- reactive({
    second_data() %>%
      filter(between(mpg, input$range_mpg[1], input$range_mpg[2]))
  })
  
  output$test_table <- renderTable({
    third_data()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

To summarize, here's the expected behavior:

- when I select the first input, the range should be updated to correspond to the cars in the category selected in the first input (DONE).
- when I change the range, the first input should be updated, so that it displays categories of cars that are in this range.

Any idea on how to do this, or on another "app workflow"?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for

```
mtcars$category <- rep(c("A", "B"), each = 16)
mtcars2 <- mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("car_name")

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("car_name", "car name", unique(mtcars2$car_name),
              multiple = TRUE, selected = c("Mazda RX4", "Dodge Challenger",
                                            "AMC Javelin", "Camaro Z28")),
  selectInput("category", "category", NULL, multiple = TRUE),
  sliderInput("range_mpg", "range of mpg",
              min = 0,
              max = 0,
              value = c(0, 0)),
  tableOutput("test_table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  first_data <- eventReactive(input$car_name, {
    mtcars2 %>%
      filter(car_name %in% input$car_name)
  })

  observeEvent(first_data(), {
    updateSelectInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "category",
      choices = unique(mtcars2$category),
      selected = unique(first_data()$category)
    )
    updateSliderInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "range_mpg",
      min = min(mtcars2$mpg),
      max = max(mtcars2$mpg),
      value = c(min(first_data()$mpg), max(first_data()$mpg))
    )
  })

  second_data <- eventReactive(input$category, {
    first_data() %>%
      filter(category %in% input$category)
  })

  observeEvent(second_data(), {
    updateSliderInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "range_mpg",
      min = min(mtcars2$mpg),
      max = max(mtcars2$mpg),
      value = c(min(second_data()$mpg), max(second_data()$mpg))
    )

  })

  third_data <- eventReactive(input$range_mpg, {
    first_data() %>%
      filter(between(mpg, input$range_mpg[1], input$range_mpg[2]))
  })

  output$test_table <- renderTable({
    third_data()
  })
  
  observeEvent(third_data(), {
    updateSelectInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "category",
      choices = unique(mtcars2$category),
      selected = unique(third_data()$category)
    )
    
  })
  

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Not working, for example launch the app, select "Valiant" and "Duster 360" (in addition to the preselected cars), and move the lower bound of the range to 19. The range is then automatically put back at 13.3. But I think that what I'm trying to do is wrong, because making inputs dependent on each other could quite easily create infinite loops.

Comment: That is true. There is a high chance of creating infinite loop.

Comment: I just thought that putting independent inputs and showing reactively the number of cars left (in this example) could be more practical. Thanks for having spent some time on my problem though